# Implementing a singleton wrapper class that also verifies 'the singleton constructor is private'

Tags: c++, templates, singleton, crtp, enable-if

I made a singleton wrapper template class that provides the `instance()` member function and is also supposed to assert whether the singleton class has a `private` constructor. The definition is as follows:

```
template <
    class T,
    class = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_constructible<T>::value, void>::type
>
class singleton {
public:
    static T& instance() {
        static T inst;
        return inst;
    }
};
```

When I define a singleton class like:

```
class class_with_public_constr
 : public singleton<class_with_public_constr> {
public:
    class_with_public_constr() {}
    friend class singleton<class_with_public_constr>;
};
```

The code passes the `enable_if` assertion. What is wrong with my `singleton` class template?

[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e93207028e7c795)

Comment: The `T` is an incomplete type at the point of your verification, it's never constructible and hence, the `enable_if`'s condition is always evaluated to true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify the code as following and also get the error printed when the constructor is `public` (i.e. not `private`, `protected`)

```
template<typename T>
class singleton
{
public:
    // Below constructor is always invoked, because the wannabe singleton class will derive this class
    singleton () {
        static_assert(!std::is_constructible<T>::value, "the constructor is public");
    }

    static T& instance();
};
```

The client class will look like below:

```
class A : public singleton<A> 
{
  friend class singleton<A>;   
//public:  // <---------- make it `public` & you get the error!
  A() {}
};
```

Here is the [demo](http://ideone.com/x3l01s).

Comment: The question is, how to make `singleton` fail to instantiate if the constructor is public?

Comment: @MikeSeymour, from his question, somehow I get a different impression. It seems that OP is asking why his class is **not throwing error**? I am referring to this part: `... and is also supposed to assert whether the singleton class has a private constructor`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, the answer is now edited. It should be according to what you said and probably what the OP asked!

Comment: That will only assert if you create a `singleton` object, which you wouldn't do just to call the static function.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, No. The `singleton` object will be always created because the client class is deriving the `singleton<client>`. So whenever we instantiate the object of the client class, `singleton()` would be invoke by default. You can also check in the demo, I am not creating any explicit `singleton` object. Also, when you make the constructor `public`, `static_assert()` fails.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the (otherwise pointless) use of inheritance. So now the problem is how to create the "allowed" instance when the constructor is private.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, I have used the inheritance because OP has used it and in fact this is the only way to succeed what OP asks. The "allowed" instance is created because we declare `friend` (see in the example code). In short, the `singleton<T>` should be derived and should be a `friend`.

Comment: OK, fine. The point I missed is that, for `is_constructible`, "access checking is performed as if in a context unrelated to `T` and any of the `Args`." So I (wrongly) thought that a friend declaration would stop the assertion from working.

Comment: @iammilind My template would look so sexy with that ``enable_if`` as a template argument! :(